# Creating load balancer diagnostic log rule does not generate logs

Tags: azure, load-balancing

We have a single load balancer that is load balancing 2 VM's, and we're trying to pull the LoadBalancerProbeHealthStatus logs from it, hoping to figure out some things about how the load balancer is redirecting traffic. I've created a diagnostic setting rule that specifies:

- Archive to a storage account: (storage account name)
- Enable LoadBalancerAlertEvent, retention 0 (forever)
- Enable LoadBalancerProbeHealthStatus, retention 0 (forever)

And I've saved this rule. I'm expecting some kind of log container to show up in the storage account I specified, but it's been a whole day, and nothing has shown up. I'm not sure what to expect, should something have shown up by now, or have I missed a configuration somewhere that's necessary to enable load balancer logs?

Answer (score 0):

These logs are event logs and occur only when the status changes and are only available for public Load Balancer resources (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-monitor-log).  If you do not see logs when you have instances signal probe failures, please reach out to support to investigate further.